# Reasoning for math bug fix in Python

Tags: python

I put together a program in Python to use the law of cosines to figure out missing sides or angles in a triangle. The portion of the program that calculates the missing angle for a side-side-side triangle goes like so:

```
usedegrees = True
opptheta = 4
sideb = 8
sidec = 9
asqrd = opptheta**2
bsqrd = sideb**2
csqrd = sidec**2
costheta = (bsqrd+csqrd-asqrd)/(2.0*sideb*sidec)
if usedegrees:
  print degrees(acos(costheta))
else: 
  print acos(costheta)
```

It was calculating incorrectly when I assigned the `costheta` with `(bsqrd+csqrd-asqrd)/(2*sideb*sidec)` (The `costheta` variable output `0`).

So my question is, is why did the change of the `2` to `2.0` in the law of cosines formula fix the bug and make `costheta` have an output the program could work with to perform the calculation?

Comment: is this python 2? because if it is, if both the numerator and denominator are `int`s then it will automatically do an integer divide ie `5/2 == 2` instead of `5.0/2 == 2.5`

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21768286/535275

Comment: Python defaults to using integers unless otherwise "told" to use floating point numbers. The change from integer `2` to floating point `2.0` makes it switch.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the explanation, and my apologies for the duplicate question